# R: Scrape multiple urls using pipechain commands in Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest, httr

I have a chr list with multiple urls'. I want to download content from each of these urls'.

To avoid writing out hundreds of commands, I wish to automate the process with a loop using lapply.

However my command returns an error. Is it possible to scrape from multiple urls?

### Current Approaches

#### Long method: Works, but I wish to automate it

```
urls <-c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England")

library(rvest)
library(httr) # required for user_agent command

uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", user_agent(uastring))
session2<-jump_to(session, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus")
session3<-jump_to(session, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia")
writeBin(session2$response$content, "test1.txt") 
writeBin(session3$response$content, "test2.txt")
```

#### Automated/loop: Does not work.

```
urls <-c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England")

library(rvest)
library(httr) # required for user_agent command

uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", user_agent(uastring))
lapply(urls, .%>% jump_to(session))
Error: is.session(x) is not TRUE
```

### Summary

I wish to automate the following two processes, `jump_to()` and `writeBin()`, as shown in the code below

```
session2<-jump_to(session, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus")
session3<-jump_to(session, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia")
writeBin(session2$response$content, "test1.txt") 
writeBin(session3$response$content, "test2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
urls <-c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England")
require(httr)
require(rvest)
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", user_agent(uastring))

outfile <- sprintf("%s.html", sub(".*/", "", urls))

jump_and_write <- function(x, url, out_file){
  tmp = jump_to(x, url)
  writeBin(tmp$response$content, out_file) 
}

for(i in seq_along(urls)){
  jump_and_write(session, urls[i], outfile[i])
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why the original method of using `lapply()` did not work? My understanding is that it loops a function over a list, much in the same a `for()` loop works.

Comment: You used passed the arguments in the wrong order: `lapply(urls, .%>% jump_to(session))` uses `jump_to(url, session)` but `jump_to` expects `jump_to(session, url)`. You can fix this by using `lapply(urls, .%>% jump_to(session, .))`. Have a look at ?magrittr::`%>%` (place ` around the %>%)

Comment: Thanks. Would it possible to pipechain the final `writeBin()` command?